# @Transactional need to define multiple times

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

In Spring Boot project .
Why do we need to define @Transacational to both the methods .
I have one method saveData() from that i am calling another method saveMethod().
why do we need to define @Transactional at both metods ?
provided code for refenece.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class CallFunctionController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @GetMapping("/call")
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity saveData(){
        saveMethod();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
    private void saveMethod() {
        Employee employee= new Employee();
        employee.setName("pppppp");
        employee.setDepartmentId(1L);
        employee.setSalary(20L);
        employee.setPerformance("BAD");
        employee.setStatus(true);
        Employee employees= employeeRepository.save(employee);
        Customer customer= new Customer();
     

        customer.setCustomerId(employees.getEmployeeId());
        customer.setActive(employee.getStatus());
        customer.setEmail("sam@test.com");
        customer.setPhoneNo("xxxxxxxx");
        customer.setLastName("wwwwwww");
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
}
```

*Why do we need to define   @Transactional(rollbackFor = SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class) from savedata() method and for saveMethod()*